# Add 2nd SSID to Ubiquiti WiFi using VLANs

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a SonicWALL firewall with multiple VLANs.

```
ID  Network         Purpose
2   192.168.2.1/24  All Internal Traffic
3   192.168.3.1/24  All IoT Traffic
4   192.168.4.1/24  All WiFi Traffic
```

I am trying to create another VLAN for Guest WiFi. I've created VLAN 5 with 192.168.5.1/24.

I am using Cisco SG200 smart switches. Right now, my relevant ports are set up as:

```
Port  Mode    Membership
1     Trunk   1U, 2T, 3T, 4T
4     Access  4U
```

Port 4 then goes to my Ubiquiti UniFi access point. My UniFi has one SSID set up (MrPeanut). Its device IP is 192.168.4.2. I don't have any VLAN options set in the wireless network on the UniFi. (I also have the Network settings on the UniFi of 192.168.1.1/24 but I don't think that's being used?)

***My Goal***

I'm trying to add my VLAN 5 to the Ubiquiti UniFi using SSID "MrPeanutGuest". However, I can't quite get it to work. I've added *MrPeanutGuest* under Wireless Networks in my UniFi settings.

**Questions**

1. Do I need to set the VLAN on *MrPeanut* as 4 and *MrPeanutGuest* as 5?
2. Do I need to change my Cisco port VLANs so that port 4 includes VLAN 5? If so, I have to change it from Access to Trunk, correct?
3. Is the AP Device IP of 192.168.4.2 going to be an issue?

Comment: With my networking hat on: Can I ask one simple question? Why are you configuring VLANs, if your IP addressing is a 24bit scheme?  The whole point of VLANs is to separate IP networks.  Since you are using the same pool of IP addresses for all VLANs, I would suggest you get rid of the VLANs and have MrPeanut and MrPeanutGuest on the same native VLAN (no 802.1Q tagging).

Comment: @pythonian Well, I am learning by doing, so I may not have a good reason. Isn't a device with IP 192.168.2.2/24 on a different network than 192.168.3.3/24? (They can't access each other on my network, but maybe that's because of my firewall.) Or is that your point -- that they're on a different network and therefore don't need VLANs?

Comment: Yes you are correct - 192.168.2.2/24 on a different network than 192.168.3.3/24 are on separate networks.  Thinking more about this, the only way you can use 1 SSID with multiple networks is to make use of VLANs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without my networking hat on:

1. Yes, both MrPeanut and MrPeanutGuest should be separated by VLANs. So, both VLAN4 and VLAN5 should be Trunk ports.
2. Yes, please add VLAN5 as Trunk port to Cisco port 4.
3. Yes, Usually your AP IP should be set to Native VLAN (no 802.1Q tagging).